# Hi this is my PowerShell code I am writing this code to validate IP and add them in a text file

Tags: powershell, winforms, syntax, constructor

When I run the code I get some error

I am not a PowerShell expert I have referred online documents and code and wrote this code so please help me out

My code :

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Create the form
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "IP Blocking Automation"
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400, 400)
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
$Form.MaximizeBox = $False

# Create the xyz label
$LabelTeam = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$LabelTeam.Text = "xyz"
$LabelTeam.AutoSize = $True
$LabelTeam.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$LabelTeam.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Form.Controls.Add($LabelTeam)

# Create the IP add automation label
$LabelAutomation = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$LabelAutomation.Text = "IP add automation"
$LabelAutomation.AutoSize = $True
$LabelAutomation.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($Form.ClientSize.Width - $LabelAutomation.PreferredSize.Width - 10, 10)
$LabelAutomation.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)
$Form.Controls.Add($LabelAutomation)

# Create the xyz logo picture box
$PictureBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$PictureBox.Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("C:\Path\to\xyzLogo.png")
$PictureBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 100)
$PictureBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($Form.ClientSize.Width - $PictureBox.Width) / 2, 50)
$Form.Controls.Add($PictureBox)

# Create the input text box
$TextBoxInput = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBoxInput.Multiline = $True
$TextBoxInput.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
$TextBoxInput.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, $PictureBox.Bottom + 20)
$TextBoxInput.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($Form.ClientSize.Width - 20, 200)
$Form.Controls.Add($TextBoxInput)

# Create the error label
$LabelError = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$LabelError.ForeColor = "Red"
$LabelError.AutoSize = $True
$LabelError.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, $PictureBox.Bottom + 10)
$Form.Controls.Add($LabelError)

# Create the Add button
$ButtonAdd = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ButtonAdd.Text = "Add"
$ButtonAdd.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($Form.ClientSize.Width - $ButtonAdd.Width) / 2, $LabelError.Bottom + 10)
$Form.Controls.Add($ButtonAdd)

# Function to validate and process the input IP
Function Validate-IP {
    $IP = $TextBoxInput.Text.Trim()

    # Check if IP is in the prohibited subnets
    $ProhibitedSubnets = @("111.112.44.0/24", "111.112.45.0/24")
    $IsProhibited = $ProhibitedSubnets | ForEach-Object { Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -PingType -Quiet }

    If ($IP -match "^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$") {
        If ($IsProhibited) {
            $LabelError.Text = "Cannot add IP from prohibited subnet."
        } ElseIf ($IP -like "10.*" -or $IP -like "172.*" -or $IP -like "192.168.*") {
            $LabelError.Text = "Cannot add private IP."
        } Else {
            $LabelError.Text = ""
            # Process the valid IP (add your code here)
            Write-Host "Valid IP: $IP"

            # Append the valid IP to a text file
            $IP | Out-File -Append -FilePath "C:\Path\to\IPList.txt"
        }
    } Else {
        $LabelError.Text = "Invalid IP format."
    }
}

$ButtonAdd.Add_Click({ Validate-IP })

# Set the form's background color
$Form.BackColor = "LightGray"

# Set the font color for labels and buttons
$LabelTeam.ForeColor = "White"
$LabelAutomation.ForeColor = "White"
$ButtonAdd.ForeColor = "White"

# Set the background color for labels and buttons
$LabelTeam.BackColor = "DarkBlue"
$LabelAutomation.BackColor = "DarkBlue"
$ButtonAdd.BackColor = "DarkBlue"

$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

My error

```
PS P:\automation\automate IP\using command> . 'P:\automation\automate IP\using command\IP_GUI.ps1'
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Subtraction'.
At P:\automation\automate IP\using command\IP_GUI.ps1:24 char:1
+ $LabelAutomation.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($Form.Cli ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Subtraction:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
 
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "Point" and the argument count: "3".
At P:\automation\automate IP\using command\IP_GUI.ps1:32 char:26
+ ... .Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, $LabelTeam.Bottom + 2 ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
 
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Subtraction'.
At  P:\automation\automate IP\using command\IP_GUI.ps1:33 char:1
+ $TextBoxInput.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($Form.ClientSize. ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Subtraction:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
 
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Division'.
At  P:\automation\automate IP\using command\IP_GUI.ps1:40 char:1
+ $ButtonAdd.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($Form.ClientSi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Division:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

I want you to write a PowerShell script that has a GUI good looking and has written in at top left corner xyz

and upper right corner IP blocking automation

and below it should have a big input area where we can only add 1 IP in 1 line without space

It should check IP conditions for each IP and also it should not allow to add IP of subnet 111.112.44.0/24 111.112.45.0/24

Also it should allow to add only public IP not private IP

make the GUI bit colorful and add a xyz logo to it

at the bottom of input field there should be a Add button

Show error above input field

Also when you click on add button try to fill a text file with the valid IP

Comment: Change `New-Object System.Drawing.Point($Form.ClientSize.Width - $LabelAutomation.PreferredSize.Width - 10, 10)` to `New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($Form.ClientSize.Width - $LabelAutomation.PreferredSize.Width - 10), 10)`, etc.

Comment: Writing GUI applications in PowerShell is so painful. I'd strongly recommend against it. For what you're trying to do, using WinForms is going to be so much faster and easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Your **[`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object) syntax was incorrect**.

Use *either* (applies analogously to all your `New-Object` calls:

```bash
# New-Object requires *argument syntax*:
#   Note the (...) around the subtraction only.
#   The first argument positionally binds to -TypeName,
#   the second one to -ArgumentList
New-Object System.Drawing.Point ($Form.ClientSize.Width - $LabelAutomation.PreferredSize.Width - 10), 10
```

*or*, **preferably, in PSv5+**, using the **[intrinsic static `::new()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#new-method-for-types)** that PowerShell exposes on all types, which enables use of **true *method-call syntax***:

```bash
[System.Drawing.Point]::new(
  $Form.ClientSize.Width - $LabelAutomation.PreferredSize.Width - 10, 
  10
)
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> ```bash
> New-Object System.Drawing.Point($Form.ClientSize.Width - $LabelAutomation.PreferredSize.Width - 10, 10)
> ```

is an example of - unfortunately very common - ***pseudo* method-call syntax**, which is **best avoided**:

- The `(...)` part after `System.Drawing.Point` *looks like* a list of arguments in a *method call*, but it *isn't*; while in practice that often does *not* matter, in the case at hand it does.
- Your call is the equivalent of the following `New-Object` call:

  ```bash
  # !! BROKEN
  New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Point `
             -ArgumentList ($Form.ClientSize.Width - $LabelAutomation.PreferredSize.Width - 10, 10)
  ```
- `New-Object`, as a *command* (cmdlet) operates in PowerShell's *argument[-parsing]* mode, i.e. it is invoked *like a shell command*, with *whitespace*-separated arguments, with no need for `(...)` enclosure *as a whole*.

  - Argument mode has different parsing rules than *expression* mode, and within expression mode the syntax for the *list of arguments in a method call* (e.g. `.someMethod(..., ...)`) is subtly different yet again.

    - See the conceptual [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing) help topic for basic information about PowerShell's two fundamental parsing modes.
- In argument mode - and even in a `(...)` enclosed *expression* outside of a method call - `,` doesn't separate *arguments*, it acts as `,` the [array constructor ("comma") *operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-):

  - The `,` operator has surprisingly high [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operator_Precedence), so that an expression such as `10-5, 2` is parsed as `10 - (5, 2)`, i.e. an attempt to subtract an *array* from the number `10` - this results in the error you saw:

    ```bash
    # !! BREAKS, because it is the same as: 10 - (5, 2) 
    Write-Output (10-5, 2)
    ```