# Retaining double quotes in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible

I am trying to use a windows file path in Powershell script via Ansible. However Powershell omits the opening and closing double quotes when it executes the command. Therefore the command fails.

Command I'm trying to run via win_shell Ansible module:

```
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("C:\projectcorp.pfx", "$(ssl_cert_passcode}")
```

Powershell omits the double quotes and considers the file path as simply `C:\closingcorp.pfx` and so the powershell command fails with an error.

I tried several options to go around this such as

- Storing the file path in a variable and then using it in the command-- does not solve the issue.
- Tried using few escape characters like ` and \ to escape the double quotes -- still the quotes are omitted

Please note that the same command works fine via powershell when I run it manually

I'm very new to ansible and any help on this issue is greatly appreciated.

I was trying to pass the cert and the passcode in the below command:

```
Scert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("C:\project.pfx", "$(ssl_cert_passcode}")
```

But powershell omits the opening and closing double quotes of the 1st parameter when running the command.

Here is the ansible task in my playbook:

```yaml
  - name: Run command to import SSL certificate into VisualSVN Server
   
win_shell: |
     New-Object  System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("C:\projectcorp.pfx", "${ssl_cert_passcode}")
   args:
     executable: powershell.exe
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you considered using `to_json` filter in your Ansible playbook?

Comment: Tried both to_json and -Escape. The command that creates the X509Certificate object doesn't accept such params

Comment: Here is a reference to the powershell command I'm running via ansible.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x509certificate2-ctor(system-string-system-security-securestring)

Comment: `$(ssl_cert_passcode}` should be `$(ssl_cert_passcode)` escaping a character is done with backtic ` character in powershell e.g. `` `"C:\closingcorp.pfx`" ``

Comment: Looks like you can use [this filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/quote_filter.html) to escape/quote the string args correctly: `$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2({{ cert_path | ansible.windows.quote(shell='powershell') }}, {{ ssl_cert_passcode | ansible.windows.quote(shell='powershell') }})`

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show the YAML you're using to invoke the command?

Comment: Sure, editing it right away

Comment: Using the quote filter doesn't work @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 1):

The parser acts on double quotes at parse time, not at execution time, if I can make that distinction. So if you say

```
$var = "This is my var"
$var
```

The value assigned to var is a string whose content contains no quotes.

If you want the quotes in the string,  you have to say

```
$var = '"This is my var"'
$var
```

The outer single quotes will be swallowed by the parser, but the inner double quotes will be part of the string.

Comment: You're absolutely right Walter. However this method of preserving double quotes doesn't work for the X509Certificate command.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to call `powershell.exe` *explicitly*, because it is used *by default* by the [`ansible.windows.win_shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_shell_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-windows-win-shell-module) module.

- In fact, it is your explicit call that caused the effective loss of the double quotes:

  - `"` characters that are to be retained as part of PowerShell code passed to the PowerShell CLI's `-Command` (`-c`) parameter must be *escaped as* **`\"`** (this paramter is implied for [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the *Windows PowerShell* CLI, but must be specified with [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh), the *PowerShell (Core) 7+* CLI)
  - Because `win_shell` *itself* uses such a CLI call - and automatically performs this escaping for the *implicit* call - you'd have to escape your `"` characters *yourself* in order for them to be passed through to your nested *explicit* call.

Therefore (`executable: powershell.exe` was removed):

```yaml
- name: Run command to import SSL certificate into VisualSVN Server
  win_shell: New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 "C:\projectcorp.pfx", "{{ ssl_cert_passcode }}"
```

Note:

- I've replaced `"${ssl_cert_passcode}"` - a *PowerShell* variable reference - with
  `"{{ ssl_cert_passcode }}"`, i.e. an *Ansible* [variable reference](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html), because I assume you need the latter.

  - A *more robust alternative* - especially if the value of an ANSI variable isn't known in advance and may itself contain `"` characters - is to let the [`ansible.windows.quote`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/quote_filter.html) *filter* with argument `shell='powershell'`handle the quoting for you, in which case no `"..."` enclosure is needed:

    ```yaml
    - name: Run command to import SSL certificate into VisualSVN Server
      win_shell: New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 "C:\projectcorp.pfx", {{ ssl_cert_passcode | ansible.windows.quote(shell='powershell') }}
    ```
- Also note that I've removed `(` and `)` from your [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object) call, as they amount to *pseudo method syntax*; while they wouldn't have done any harm in this particular case, they amount to a conceptual confusion that is best avoided: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76615570/45375).

Comment: That works!!! Thank you so much @mklement0