# Powershell script error "The system cannot find the file specified (0x80070002)" when run as task

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, file-permissions

I created a Powershell script using an account that is part of the Administrators Group. I can run it without error if I manually trigger it as a standalone script. It launches a web scraping python script and then uploads the resulting csv file to my webserver. But when I make that script a scheduled task, I get the "The system cannot find the specified file" error when I manually trigger the task and it fails to write a log file. Here is the standalone code:

```
\# Define the path to the Python executable, your Python script, and the CSV file

$pythonExe = "C:\\Python312\\pythonw.exe"

$scriptPath = "D:\\OneDrive\\Websites\\Howe Street Reporter\\assets\\files\\Most_Actives_TSXV-EG.py"

$csvFilePath = "D:\\OneDrive\\Websites\\Howe Street Reporter\\assets\\files\\TSXV_Most-Actives.csv"

\# FTP/SFTP details

$serverAddress = "ftp://173.231.203.237" # Change to your server's address

$remotePath = "/public_html/wp-content/themes/Howe-Street-Reporter/" # The directory on the server where the file will be uploaded

\# Retrieve credentials from Windows Credential Manager

$credential = Get-StoredCredential -Target "173.231.203.237"

\# Run the Python script

& "$pythonExe" "$scriptPath"

\# Upload the CSV file

$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

$webClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($credential.UserName, $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)

$uri = New-Object System.Uri("$serverAddress$remotePath" + \[System.IO.Path\]::GetFileName("$csvFilePath"))

$webClient.UploadFile($uri, "$csvFilePath")
```

Here is the scheduled task code:

```
\# Define the path to the Python executable, your Python script, the CSV file, and the log file
$pythonExe = "C:\Python312\python.exe"
$scriptPath = "D:\OneDrive\Websites\Howe Street Reporter\assets\files\Most_Actives_TSXV-EG.py"
$csvFilePath = "D:\OneDrive\Websites\Howe Street Reporter\assets\files\TSXV_Most-Actives.csv"
$logFilePath = "D:\OneDrive\Websites\Howe Street Reporter\assets\files\TaskLog.txt"

\# FTP/SFTP details
$serverAddress = "ftp://173.231.203.237" # Change to your server's address
$remotePath = "/public_html/wp-content/themes/Howe-Street-Reporter/" # The directory on the server where the file will be uploaded

\# Retrieve credentials from Windows Credential Manager
$credential = Get-StoredCredential -Target "173.231.203.237"

\# Create the script block to run the Python script and then upload the CSV file with error logging
$scriptBlock = {
    Try {
        Set-Location "D:\OneDrive\Websites\Howe Street Reporter\assets\files"
        & $pythonExe $scriptPath

        $webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
        $webClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($credential.UserName, $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)
        $uri = New-Object System.Uri($serverAddress + $remotePath + [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($csvFilePath))
        $webClient.UploadFile($uri, $csvFilePath)
    } Catch {
        $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        $timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        "$timestamp - Error: $errorMessage" | Out-File -FilePath $logFilePath -Append
    }
}

\# Create the scheduled task action with the script block
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "Powershell.exe" -Argument "-Command $scriptBlock"

\# Create the trigger to run the task every 15 minutes
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date) -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 15)

\# Register the task
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "RunPythonScriptAndUploadCSV" -Description "Runs a Python script every 15 minutes and uploads a CSV file" -RunLevel Highest
```

I made sure the permissions were full control. I ran the powershell ISE as administrator. The task scheduler was using an account that is part of the Administrators Group. I ran a stripped down version of a task that only wrote a log file to the same file location and it worked. I am at a loss. I am new to this, so may be missing something obvious. Forgive me if this is the case.

Comment: As an aside: ``\`` (a backslash) has _no_ special meaning in PowerShell, so there's never a need to use ``\\`` in file-system paths in order to escape ``\`` chars. 
(PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) - where needed - is `\``, the so-called _backtick_.)

Comment: As an aside: It's best to pseudo method syntax: Instead of `New-Object SomeType(arg1, ...)`, use `New-Object SomeType [-ArgumentList] arg1, ...` - PowerShell cmdlets, scripts and functions are invoked like _shell commands_, not like _methods_. That is, no parentheses around the argument list, and _whitespace_-separated arguments (`,` constructs an _array_ as a _single argument_, as needed for `-ArgumentList`). However, method syntax _is_ required if you use the PSv5+ `[SomeType]::new()` constructor-call method. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76615570/45375)

Comment: The most likely cause of your problem: `-Command` CLI calls require `"` chars. meant to be part of PowerShell code to be executed to be escaped as `\"`  - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124361/45375).

Comment: "*The task scheduler was using an account that is part of the Administrators Group*". If that was the case, I would expect a [`-User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask#-user) (and a password) defined in your `Register-ScheduledTask` command. I guess that your script actually [runs under the SYSTEM account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612478/1701026) which has different permissions

Comment: Does the user (system?) under which you run the scheduled task have access to D:\OneDrive ?

Comment: @mklement0, thank you for the primer on quotation marks. I was able to make the necessary corrections. I also had to define an absolute path to powershell.exe, but it all works now. Just dealing with some SSL errors that the task is throwing. The python code doesn't throw them, just when its run through the scheduler. Will figure it out. Thanks again!